# "lead to" + verb/gerund/noun

Tags: grammar

Which of the sentences below are correct?

> they could only lead us to having less disposable income

vs

> they could only lead us to have less disposable income

Could I use "lead to + verb"? My teacher told me that it is "lead to + noun", but here it says that I can use it in various ways https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lead+them+to.

Comment: The most natural way would be: "They could only lead to us having less disposable income.